# Java - Scanner fails to read in integer after loop?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

My application has a loop that repeats the same selection of choices until told to quit.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
while(running == true){
  System.out.println("Select an option (1-4):");
  System.out.println("1: Add an item to your store");
  System.out.println("2: Search for an item in your store");
  System.out.println("3: Remove an item from your store");
  System.out.println("4: Buy an item from the store:");
  System.out.println("5: Exit this application");
  int option = scan.nextInt();
  if(option == ... etc.
}
```

On the second iteration of the loop, the inserted integer does not get accepted and returns the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException   at
>   java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)  at
>   java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)     at
>   java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)  at
>   java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)  at
>   storeproject.StoreProject.main(StoreProject.java:27)

Comment: have you tried to use `import java.util.Scanner;` ?

Comment: @JohnReyM.Baylen If he didn't it wouldn't work the first time

Comment: what are you inputting?

Comment: Tried your code and it was working as expected, of course except if you inputted anything non-numeric.

Answer (score 0):

You get this `InputMismatchException` because your enter is not a number, maybe it is a non numeric data or it is not an Integer number, because you are trying to get `nextInt()`. Hope it helps you!

Comment: so what's the essential difference between your code and OP's which makes the difference in behavior?

Comment: Nothing special different here, I just done optimization and ensure that the problem is not with code, maybe there is some other reason that cause that exception. And also I figured out the the exception reason

Comment: So it has nothing to do with OP's question then.  If you need to clarify his code is correct, do it in comment.

Comment: I said the reason of the exception, did you read carefully read the answer?? he said that he got `InputMismatchException` I figured out the reason.

Comment: 1. it was added after my initial comment. 2. 90% of your answer is still talking something irrelevant.

Comment: StackOverflow is a community moderated site.  You seems taking comments and downvote offensive but they are simply the way SO suggest for improvement of answer.  Actually just leave your "Note" in the answer will make your answer something acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what's going on.

The next int needs to have exactly a number and only a number. any non integer values, alpha and punctuations before or after the input will give you that error. I tried it out:

**Code:**

```
public class ScannerTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(true){
            System.out.println("Select an option (1-4):");
            System.out.println("1: Add an item to your store");
            System.out.println("2: Search for an item in your store");
            System.out.println("3: Remove an item from your store");
            System.out.println("4: Buy an item from the store:");
            System.out.println("5: Exit this application");
            int option = scan.nextInt();
            System.out.println(option);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
5
5
Select an option (1-4):
1: Add an item to your store
2: Search for an item in your store
3: Remove an item from your store
4: Buy an item from the store:
5: Exit this application
6
6
Select an option (1-4):
1: Add an item to your store
2: Search for an item in your store
3: Remove an item from your store
4: Buy an item from the store:
5: Exit this application
5.
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
    at ScannerTest.main(ScannerTest.java:17)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: *"...any non integer values, **spaces**, alpha and punctuations..."* .  Spaces are actually fine.

Comment: @AdrianShum: Thank you, removed spaces

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
while (scan.hasNextInt() && running)
```